# Why is VideoView not playing Video?

Tags: android, mobile, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video by starting it when the Activity starts.

However,I am just getting a black screen when the Activity starts.

I do not understand why this is occurring.

Is this not the proper way to configure and play a video?

HelloMoonFragment:

```
public class HelloMoonFragment extends Fragment {
private AudioPlayer mPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
private Button mPlayButton;
private Button mStopButton;
private Button mPauseButton;
private Button mResumeButton;
private Button mStartVideo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon,parent,false);

    mPlayButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_playButton);
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.play(getActivity());

        }
    });
    mStopButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_stopButton);
    mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    mResumeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.helloMoon_startButton);
    mResumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.resume();
        }
    });

    mPauseButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_pauseButton);
    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.pause();


        }
    });

    mStartVideo = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_startVideo);
    mStartVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.stop();
}



}
```

VideoActivity:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
private String mVideoPath = "android.resource://" + "com.tubbs.android.hellomoon" + "/" + "R.raw/apollo_17_stroll";
private Uri mVideo;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    mVideo = Uri.parse(mVideoPath);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_startVideo);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.start();





}
}
```

activity_video.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/hellomoon_startVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try videoView.setOnPreparedListener first, implement the onPrepared method and inside that method, call videoView.start(). see if it work :-?.

I have a git repo that demonstrate the simple way to play view by videoview, please have a look, and feel free to clone it if it works for you: https://github.com/eneim/android-training-tutorial/tree/master/ZCustomVideoView

they are quite old, so use it at your own risk

Comment: I appreciate the reply but I simply forgot to call videoView.setUriPath(Uri). It worked after that.